# How to clone paint a mirrored object?

Tags: modifiers, texture-painting

Whenever I try it paints in perfect symmetry along both sides of the object. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or some other information to clarify exactly what is happening?

Comment: Sorry so I have a object that I mirror in meshmixer then exported. I want to use the clone tool so my object doesn't have such a mirrored and symmetrical look on both sides. However when I try to use the clone tool it paints both sides of the object, not just the one. I'm assuming cause the uv's are mirrored

Comment: If I understand correctly, I guess you need to apply the Mirror modifier and re-unwrap the object

Comment: I'll try to show a possible solution later, it involves applying the mirror modifier and then creating a new UV layer that involves the full mesh and a new 0 alpha image to paint on top of the existing texture.